# How to add datalabels in stacked bar/line chart in chartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to add the datalabels onto my stacked bar/line chart in chartJS specifically at the line chart area. Because the values are not aligned with the Y-Axis, therefore I wanted to use chartJS datalabels plugin to show the values on top of the line chart only for better clarification when it is printed out.
What I tried:

```
#1 putting into config
const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
      plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          anchor: 'end',
          align: 'top',
          formatter: function(value, context) {
            return GetValueFormatted(value);
          },
          borderRadius: 4,
          color: 'white',
          font: {
            weight: 'bold'
          },
          formatter: Math.round,
          padding: 6
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Menu Performance Chart'
        },
      },
      scales: {
        y: {
          stacked: true
        }
      }
    },
  };

#2 putting into specific dataset
const data = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Sub Total Sales (RM)',
        data: [
          '111',
          '22',
          '31',
          '12',
          '71',
          '110',
          '22',
        ],
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        stack: 'combined',
        type: 'bar'
      },
      {
        label: 'Total Amount Sold',
        data: [
          '11',
          '2',
          '3',
          '1',
          '7',
          '10',
          '2',
        ],
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
        stack: 'combined',
        datalabels: {
          color: '#FFCE56'
        }
      },
    ]
  };
```

I even tried the two at the same time to see if there were any results. Could anyone assist me with this? Thank you in advance.

Here is my code demo in JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4gat7rzs/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin is not registered. See doc: https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#registration

You should add the datalabels plugin instance to the chart config:

```
  const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels], // <- MUST BE ADDED
    options: {
    ....
```